# Writing file to bucket fails on Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing an application in Ruby on Elastic Beanstalk in which I download a file from a remote server and write it to an object in a bucket.

```
require 'open-uri'
...
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['mybucket']
f = open(params[:url]) #using open-uri
obj = bucket.objects[params[:key]]
obj.write[f] #<< fails here
```

The last line, however, fails with the following exception in the log:

`:data must be provided as a String, Pathname, File, or an object that responds to #read and #eof?`

I know, however, from executing the same `#open` on my machine, that `f` is a `StringIO` object, which does have `#read` and `#eof?`.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error during zip file upload on `S3` and finally this worked for me:

```
zip_data = File.read(zip_file_path)
```

means, zip_data will be the object at the zip file path that is located in your tmp directory.

Hope, this will work for you also.